# Android Studio add Switch to the left side of a textview in XML

Tags: android, xml

Similarly to adding an icon to the left of a textview using `android:drawableleft="..."`, I want to do something similar except with a predefined `switch` in the same XML file. How do I go by doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/switch" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Switch Text" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

In case of Radio Buttons or Checkbox you can always use something like this

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```